# Add class to the next div with specific class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a table and when I clicked on "heading" I would like to add "open" class to the next divs who have the class "sub" with jQuery.

My code don't work :

```
function table_show() {
    jQuery('.heading th').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery(this).nextUntil('.heading').addClass('open');
    });
}
```

Can I have some help please ?

```
<table>
    <tr class="heading"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
    <tr class="heading"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
</table>
```

Example :

```
<table>
    <tr class="heading"></tr>
    <tr class="sub open"></tr>
    <tr class="sub open"></tr>
    <tr class="sub open"></tr>
    <tr class="heading"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
    <tr class="sub"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are clicking on your `td` inside the `heading` class, use `jQuery(this).parent()` to get back to the `.heading` element

You can also remove the `th` from the click like `jQuery('.heading').click` and then you don't need `.parent()`

```js
function table_show() {
  jQuery('.heading th').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery(this).parent().nextUntil('.heading').addClass('open');
  });
}

table_show()
```

```css
.open {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="heading"><th>heading</th></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><th>sub</th></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><th>sub</th></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><th>sub</th></tr>
  <tr class="heading"><th>heading</th></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><th>sub</th></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><th>sub</th></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><th>sub</th></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add `open` to the siblings to `TR` elements, thus use `.closest()` to traverse up to it, then perform the desired operation.

```
jQuery(this).closest('.heading').nextUntil('.heading').addClass('open');
```

```js
function table_show() {
  jQuery('.heading th').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).closest('.heading').nextUntil('.heading').addClass('open');
  });
}

table_show()
```

```css
.open {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="heading">
    <th>heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="heading">
    <th>heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*OR*, Attach event handler with `TR`

```
jQuery('.heading').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).nextUntil('.heading').addClass('open');
});
```

```js
function table_show() {
  jQuery('.heading').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).nextUntil('.heading').addClass('open');
  });
}

table_show()
```

```css
.open {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="heading">
    <th>heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="heading">
    <th>heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <th>sub</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```